# C++ error with just Visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```
#include <iostream>   
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int Pass;
    cout << "Enter Pass Please";
    cin >> Pass;
    switch (Pass)
    {
    case 1996:
    {
        cout << "O" << endl;
    }
    break;
    case 2015:
    {
        cout << "N\n";
    }
    break;
    default:
        cout << "Z" << endl;
        break;
        system("PAUSE");
    }
}
```

Whats wrong with this code when i run it on visual studio consle app just disappear after writing value of pass like its no system pause

Comment: Because your pause is *after* `break;` ... If you want the console to stay open in VS use Ctrl + F5.

Comment: Move `system("PAUSE");` outside the `switch` statement.

Comment: Don't try to pause your command-line program right before it ends. That's just so extremely *wrong* on many levels.

Comment: So what i can use to see my program without pause Christian ?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>   
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int Pass;
    cout << "Enter Pass Please";
    cin >> Pass;
    switch (Pass)
    {
    case 1996:
    {
        cout << "O" << endl;
    }
    break;
    case 2015:
    {
        cout << "N\n";
    }
    break;
    default:
        cout << "Z" << endl;
        break;

    }
   system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: Some questions should not be answered, but if you must, explain what you did, why, and how it will resolve the problem in the question. Code only answers breed [Cargo Cult Programmers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming)